# How do the contents of Abstract Algebra by I.N Herstein compare to others?

Tags: abstract-algebra, book-recommendation, advice

I recently ordered this book, which was much thinner than I expected, only 230 pages (I didn't realize this information was already online!). When I study a math subject I like to understand it well, meaning that a lot of content is covered, and it looks like not a lot is covered in this book. The table of contents is:

1. Things Familiar and Less Familiar (just reviewing some stuff required for the book)
2. Groups
3. The Symmetric Group
4. Ring Theory
5. Fields
6. Special Topics (Optional)

As you can see, not much is covered as, say, *A First Course in Abstract Algebra*. I already did Calc 1, 2, and 3, and an intro-to-proofs book. I'm also studying linear algebra using a theory-based book right now, if that helps.

My question is: Is this book right for me? The only reason I chose it  was because of the author's informal style, but as I'm typing this I'm realizing that I'm actually surviving a theory-based linear algebra textbook (which is indeed formal) so now I'm reconsidering the book before I decide to commit to it long-term (I don't know if "long-term" is the right term since it's so short ).

So should I go for it? If so, then what other book can I use *after* this one?

Comment: I think it actually depends on your background. Read starting chapters of the book and see how you feel. I am also taking abstract algebra but from the book *Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Gallian*